# Converting Dask dataframe with column type dask.dataframe.core.Series to dataframe through dask_array

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I am new to `dask` and but was able to complete almost all but a couple of steps for data processing. Through a series of operations, I cleaned and transformed data that has observations as columns rather than rows. At the penultimate step I had a single column of observations stored as a `dask.dataframe.core.Series`. I was hoping to use `apply` method to convert it into `dask.array` so that I can (*hopefully*) convert it to a `dataframe` through `.to_frame` (yet to check if it works at the level of column). So far, I could convert individual elements to `dask_array` through `.to_dask_array` as shown below, but the `apply` method fails for reasons that I cannot grasp. I would be grateful for any suggestions in correcting the code.

PS:

1. Metadata inferences such as `meta=(None,dask.array)` did not work.
2. The following was the way in which transpose was attained:

```
arr = ddf.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
ftr_df = dd.from_dask_array(arr.T)
```

Details of the problem

```
>>> ftr_df.head()
     0     1     2     3     ...  1306  1307  1308  1309
IDX                              ...
ABCD128  5480  5480  6240  7912  ...  2043  5480  2043  5475
ABCD129  5475  5400  2043  2043  ...  7912  5480  7912  5480
ABCD130  5470  6240  7912  6240  ...  7912  5475  7912  5480
ABCD133  5470  6240  6240  6240  ...  7912  5480  7912  5480
ABCD135  5470  6240  6240  6240  ...  2043  5480  2043  5475

[5 rows x 1310 columns]

>>> type(ftr_df[0])
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.Series'>
>>> ftr_df[0].to_dask_array(lengths=True)
dask.array<values, shape=(6,), dtype=object, chunksize=(6,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>        

>>> def darr_cast(row):
...     return row.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
...
>>> ddf['mag'] = ddf.apply(darr_cast, axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py", line 182, in raise_on_meta_error
    yield
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 6343, in _emulate
    return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 1053, in __call__
    return getattr(__obj, self.method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 8845, in apply
    return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 733, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 857, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 873, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in darr_cast
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_dask_array'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 5454, in apply
    meta = _emulate(
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 6343, in _emulate
    return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py", line 203, in raise_on_meta_error
    raise ValueError(msg) from e
ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `apply`.

You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to
determine the type of output that that function returns.

To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword.
The docstring of the Dask function you ran should have more information.

Original error is below:
------------------------
AttributeError("'Series' object has no attribute 'to_dask_array'")

Traceback:
---------
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py", line 182, in raise_on_meta_error
    yield
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 6343, in _emulate
    return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
  File "/home/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 1053, in __call__
    return getattr(__obj, self.method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 8845, in apply
    return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 733, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 857, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 873, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in darr_cast
  File "/home/softy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

>>>
```

Comment: why can't you just use [`dask.dataframe.DAtaFrame.to_dask_array`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_dask_array.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_dask_array) rather than apply? I'm having a hard time following exactly what the problem is. It would really help if you could provide a [mre] and explain the problem more clearly. We generally need less info about *how you got here* and more about *what here is* :)

Comment: Seconding - this seems overcomplicated .. maybe `ftr_df.to_dask_array().transpose()` or the similar [`.to_records()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.to_records.html)?

Comment: a couple other things - "Metadata inferences such as `meta=(None,dask.array)` did not work" - well that's not at all how to specify metadata. dask needs help understanding the numpy data types, e.g. `float32`, `uint16`, etc. so you shouldn't pass in a dask.array class to meta - it should be a valid [dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html). see the docs on [metadata](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-design.html#metadata).

Comment: Thank you. I followed an solution I saw on stackoverflow itself and was trying to adapt it. The suggested solutions are cleaner and better. Based on the suggestions, I tried `df=dd.from_dask_array(ftr_df.to_dask_array())` which also worked for me.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, sorry for the not including a minimal sample. I was sure that it was some single line conversion that was necessary, and it was.

Comment: hmm - yeah actually in your code the culprit for the error is actually just that if you apply with axis=1, the applied function needs to operate on a *pandas.Series*, not a dask one. so that's why there's no `pd.Series.to_dask_array`

Comment: fwiw - transposing a dask dataframe is legitimately hard, so if you're just starting out, you've come pretty far :) good luck and hope this helped!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado it did help, thank you! For a large dataframe, I found this link with two approaches, I could not succeed with xarray and it did not seem to offer any advantage either. I am currently using a sample (though with 10K rows), so it is still early days before the entire dataset of 100Mx10K is processed. The link is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662467/unable-to-transpose-dask-dataframe-getting-unbound-local-error

Comment: haha yep - I'm familiar with that post ;) yeah that's a big one. it might be worth preprocessing the data so you don't have to do this...